# Como instalar o patch do Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

Quando vou atualizar a IDE, não atualiza automaticamente,mas sim pede para baixar o arquivo zip.

```
Link Download:https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/download/studio/builds/android-studio-2-3-beta-1
```

Comment: Algumas atualizações do Android Studio exigem uma instalação totalmente nova. Quando isso acontece eles encaminham para o download em vez de simplesmente atualizar. É o seu caso.

Comment: Ok Cleiton, eu achei aqui como fazer esta atualização e deu tudo certo. Agradeço a sua ajuda no tópico.

Answer (score 0):

**Consegui desta forma, acho que vai ajudar a outras pessoas com esta mesma duvida.**

1. Descompacte o arquivo baixado.
2. android-studio --> bin pasta

No bin pasta que você pode encontrar o Studio.exe ou studio64.exe.

***Observação: Studio.exe é para 32-bit e studio64.exe é para 64-bit sistema.***